# How to have a graphical presentation of dependecies in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

Sometimes with medium size Android projects I struggle to have a complete vision about the dependency graph in the code, specially when some dependency injection library is used. Does anybody know about a dependency viewer in Android Studio or any other tool to make this task easier?

Comment: Right click on your project click Open module settings -> Dependencies (Tab)

Comment: that is the list of libraries my module depends on. What I'm looking for is dependencies among classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is still actual, try using the Code Iris plugin for Android Studio:
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324

It provides dependency graph on classes, packages and modules level. It is still updated and free.